# Growth limit of $\log(n^2+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

While following up a solution to find the growth limit of $(n!+2^n)(n^3+\log(n^2+1))$:

$$(n!+2^n)(n^3+\log(n^2+1))\le n^3n!+n^32^n+n!\log(n^2+1)+2^n\log(n^2+1)$$

when $n\gt3$, we have $\log(n^2+1)\le n$ and $2^n \le n!$,

$$(n!+2^n)(n^3+\log(n^2+1))\le n^3n!+n^3n!+n!(n^2+1)+n!(n^2+1)$$

Without moving on further, I think we should have based on $\log(n^2+1)\le n$ a $n$ in place of $\log(n^2+1)$, but we have $n^2+1$ in place of $\log(n^2+1)$, do you know the reason or do you think this is right?

$$(n!+2^n)(n^3+\log(n^2+1))\le n^3n!+n^3n!+n!(n^2+1)+n!(n^2+1).$$

Comment: In your first calculation you actually obtain an *equality* by expanding the product. You can bound the $\log$ by $n$ if you like, but it does not change the fact that the whole thing is $\mathcal{O}(n^3 n!)=\mathcal{O}((n+3)!)$. Perhaps one just used $\log x\leq x$ with $x=n^2+1$.

Comment: @Gray. We can say also that $logn \lt n$ for $n>3$, does not we?

Comment: Can you evaluate the limit
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} { \log(1 + n^2) \over \log(n^2)  }
$$
using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @avs. $\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$?

Comment: Is that the limit?:)  Compute the limit and see what comparison it gives you between the orders of $\log(1 + n^2)$ and $\log(n^2) = 2 \log(n)$.;)

Comment: @avs You don't need L'Hopital's for that lol. The limit is obviously $1$. You can use the fact that $\log(a+b)\ \leq a + \log(b)$ for all $a \geq 1$ and $b \geq 1$

Comment: @AdamRubinson. My original question was why the $\log(n^2+1)$ was not replaced by $n$ but instead by $n^2+1$

Comment: @AdamRubinson, if every aspect of the question was obvious to the OP, the OP wouldn't need to ask the question.  Just like if someone doesn't need to boost their self-esteem by sending "lols" and "it is obvious" toward others, would need to send those messages.

Comment: Your analogy is poor but your point is well-taken. I wasn’t writing “lols” and “its obvious” to boost my ego. Sorry if it came across as crass or belittling. But the value of that limit does seem obvious to me because $\log (10^6) $ is going to be relatively close to $\log(10^6+1)$, and this *should* be obvious if you are familiar with the properties and/or the graph of $\log$, which I would expect someone asking OP’s question to be. But clearly this was not the case and my judgement was wrong in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it's wrong to say that $O(\log(n^2+1)) = O(n^2+1),\ $ because $O(\log(a)) \neq O(a).$

Furthermore, $O(\log(n^2+1)) \neq O(n).\ $ In fact, $\ O(\log(n^2+1)) = O(\log(n))\ $ because for large enough $n:\ 2\log(n) = \log(n^2) < \log(n^2+1) < 3\log(n)$.

But I think the second sentence of Gary's comment cuts to the heart of your question:

"You can bound the $\log$ by $n$ if you like, but it does not change the fact that the whole thing is $O(n^3n!)=O((n+3)!)$."

Comment: Thank you. What is the best way to find $k$ such that $n>k$ for the growth to hold?

Comment: For what growth to hold? Please specify.

Comment: In general I mean if that is valid to assume?

Comment: You asked, "What is the best way to find $k$ such that $n>k$ for the growth to hold?". I'm not sure which growth or inequality you're referring to. You need to ask a more specific question. Do you mean, for what $n$ is $n \geq \log(n) $? Or do you mean, for what $n$ is $\log(n^2+1) \leq n^2+1?$ Or....

Comment: @Avra, finding the best upper bounds is always experimental, just like finding anything else in mathematics (which, according to Vladimir Arnol'd, "is part of physics").  Mathematics is experimental.  The textbooks and papers we see are smoothly flowing reports of results after the fact.  The process of getting those results does not have any of that smooth flow.

Comment: Oh is that what you meant Avra: how did I figure out what upper and lower bounds to use? If that’s your question then it’s because I have a good amount of experience dealing with $\log$ and know the properties of $\log.$ See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities